# Python 3.4 : Regex

Tags: python, regex

## Question

I am pulling information from YahooFinance.  I have a regex statement that finds the necessary information and divides it into 5 different groups.  I only need one group to be printed out of the five of them.  How can I do this?

```
        try:

        def isYhooStats():

            headers = {}
            headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

            req = urllib.request.Request(isUrl)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            respData = resp.read()
            dRespDataIs = respData.decode('utf-8')

            netInc= re.search(r'(Net Income)\s*(</strong>)\s*(</td><td align="right">)\s*(<strong>)\s*(\(?\d*,?\d*,\d*\)?)', dRespDataIs)

            print(netInc.groups())

        isYhooStats()

    except IndexError:
        pass

    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

## Outcome

```
('Net Income', '</strong>', '</td><td align="right">', '<strong>', '4,956,000')
```

I am printing all of the groups when I only need '4,956,000'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of `print(netInc.groups())` you can pass the number of your expected group to [`group` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group).

For example in this case you can do :

```
print(netInc.group(5))
```